# OCIError insufficient privileges while testing with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, testing, oracle-call-interface

I have a problem with my unit tests in rails and found no idea how to solve it.

If i run rake test:units i get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
OCIError: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges: CREATE TABLE 
"SCHEMA MIGRATIONS" ("VERSION" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL)
stmt.c:312:in oci8lib_191.so
Tasks: TOP => test:units => test:prepare => db:test:prepare => db:abort_if_pedning_migrations
```

My current Gemfile is

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '~> 3.1.12'

gem 'ruby-oci8', '~> 2.0.4'
gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', '~> 1.3.2'

gem 'ruby-plsql', '~> 0.4.3'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'thin'

group :assets do  
    gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.7'  
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'  
    gem 'uglifier',     '>= 1.0.3'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

database.yml contains the following data:

```
test:
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  database: service_name
  username: db_admin
  password: test
  host: name_of_host
  port: 1531
```

The same data as in database.yml works for the database connection in oracle sql developer.

Comment: Try this command (for linux debian) `sudo apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion imagemagick graphicsmagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev libreadline-dev` then do it again

Comment: Your user have `insufficient privileges`. Maybe this link helps you http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01031.htm

Comment: My user should have admin privileges. But I'll look at the oracle-link.
And i do not like it, but i'm currently working on a windows computer.

Comment: I've read the article, but i have no access to the server where the database is hosted. I've tried with SQL Developer to make some changes and for the test database i can create and delete tables. Is this not enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by adding the environment variable and running

```
rake test:units RAILS_ENV=test
```

So actually rails was accessing the wrong database.